# How can I get hits for all enabled correlation searches in Splunk in a specific timeframe without running each search separately?

Tags: splunk

I’m trying to run all enabled correlation searches in Splunk for a specific time frame together. Is there anyway instead of running each search separately we can get hits for all those searches in a single go in a specific timeframe

We have about 80 correlation searches and want to run them for a specific timeframe. But running each logic sepeately is time consUming. Kindly suggest a way if all these searches can be run together

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to set all correlation searches to covert the same time frame.  You would have to manually edit each CS in the UI or edit each savedsearches.conf file.

You probably don't want to do that, anyway.  The use cases covered by the CSs are different and changing the time windows may lead to false positive or false negative alerts/notables.

Comment: So we experienced an outage and didn’t get any alerts during that timeframe. So we were wondering if there is any other way apart from running each of these searches individually to save time and effort